# Quick one: Extending class from main script?

Tags: python

Quick question...

I have a module enemies.py, containing classes like so:

```
class zombie(game_object):
  "zombie"
  pass
```

In my main python script, I first declare the game_object class, then import enemies

```
class game_object:
  pass
import enemies
```

The enemies.py script complains that it can't find game_object (to inherit from). How do I organize this?

Just a note, I want to be able to write a game.py, `import game_mechanics` which includes the class definition for a game_object, THEN `import enemies` which includes a bunch of subclass definitions of game_object.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Each file needs to import the modules it needs.  There is no "super-global scope" in which you can import a module to automatically make it available to all other modules.  Importing `game_mechanics` will not make it available in any module other than the one you import it in.  If `enemies` needs access to things defined in `game_mechanics`, then you have to do `import game_mechanics` (or import the things you need from `game_mechanics`) from inside `enemies`.  Example:

```
# game_mechanics.py
class game_object(object):
   pass

# enemies.py
from game_mechanics import game_object
class special_object(game_object):
   pass
```

Importing modules multiple times does not waste extra memory.  The module is only loaded once, and when you import it multiple times, you just get multiple references to the same module.

Comment: But if I import it inside the module as well as the main script, won't that take up loads of extra memory?

Comment: One last technicality- What if game_object inherits from yet another class in game_mechanics.py... Will importing just game_object allow it to inherit from the other class?

Comment: @DanRedux In that case the inheritance is done entirely within the file `game_mechanics.py`. Your class in `enemies.py` only uses `game_object`, so you only need to import `game_object`.

Comment: @DanRedux: You only need to import the things you actually use.  If those objects happen to inherit from other objects that you don't import, that's fine.  You don't need to import the whole class hierarchy, only the things that you actually want to use directly in a given module.